# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'app') (Flutter web app)

Tags: flutter, dart, web, google-cloud-firestore

For more than 3 days I tried to connect my web app to firestore and try to run my web app but i can't. Please help me to solve my problem and grow my start-up faster.
Showing error like this: **TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'app')**
How can I fix this problem?

> My Flutter (index.html) code blew.

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <!--
        If you are serving your web app in a path other than the root, change the
        href value below to reflect the base path you are serving from.
    
        The path provided below has to start and end with a slash "/" in order for
        it to work correctly.
    
        For more details:
        * https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base
    
        This is a placeholder for base href that will be replaced by the value of
        the `--base-href` argument provided to `flutter build`.
      -->
      <base href="$FLUTTER_BASE_HREF">
    
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta content="IE=Edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
      <meta name="description" content="A new Flutter project.">
    
      <!-- iOS meta tags & icons -->
      <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
      <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
      <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="jaitun_admin">
      <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="icons/Icon-192.png">
    
      <title>jaitun_admin</title>
      <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
    </head>
    <body>
      <!-- This script installs service_worker.js to provide PWA functionality to
           application. For more information, see:
           https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers -->
      <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.0.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
      <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.0.1/firebase-analytics.js"></script>
      <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.0.1/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
      <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.0.1/firebase-auth.js"></script>
      
    
      <script>
    
    const firebaseConfig = {
      apiKey: "AIzaSyDmv2oj8958mbUg07FW316IxOAiOdYhPTg",
      authDomain: "jaituncustomaer.firebaseapp.com",
      databaseURL: "https://jaituncustomaer-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com",
      projectId: "jaituncustomaer",
      storageBucket: "jaituncustomaer.appspot.com",
      messagingSenderId: "771594380318",
      appId: "1:771594380318:web:aa0a3b61483d19dc2bfa0f",
      measurementId: "G-B064R6Q9GJ"
    };
    
    // Initialize Firebase
    const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    const analytics = getAnalytics(app);
    </script>
      <script>
        var serviceWorkerVersion = null;
        var scriptLoaded = false;
        function loadMainDartJs() {
          if (scriptLoaded) {
            return;
          }
          scriptLoaded = true;
          var scriptTag = document.createElement('script');
          scriptTag.src = 'main.dart.js';
          scriptTag.type = 'application/javascript';
          document.body.append(scriptTag);
        }
    
        if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
          // Service workers are supported. Use them.
          window.addEventListener('load', function () {
            // Wait for registration to finish before dropping the <script> tag.
            // Otherwise, the browser will load the script multiple times,
            // potentially different versions.
            var serviceWorkerUrl = 'flutter_service_worker.js?v=' + serviceWorkerVersion;
            navigator.serviceWorker.register(serviceWorkerUrl)
              .then((reg) => {
                function waitForActivation(serviceWorker) {
                  serviceWorker.addEventListener('statechange', () => {
                    if (serviceWorker.state == 'activated') {
                      console.log('Installed new service worker.');
                      loadMainDartJs();
                    }
                  });
                }
                if (!reg.active && (reg.installing || reg.waiting)) {
                  // No active web worker and we have installed or are installing
                  // one for the first time. Simply wait for it to activate.
                  waitForActivation(reg.installing || reg.waiting);
                } else if (!reg.active.scriptURL.endsWith(serviceWorkerVersion)) {
                  // When the app updates the serviceWorkerVersion changes, so we
                  // need to ask the service worker to update.
                  console.log('New service worker available.');
                  reg.update();
                  waitForActivation(reg.installing);
                } else {
                  // Existing service worker is still good.
                  console.log('Loading app from service worker.');
                  loadMainDartJs();
                }
              });
    
            // If service worker doesn't succeed in a reasonable amount of time,
            // fallback to plaint <script> tag.
            setTimeout(() => {
              if (!scriptLoaded) {
                console.warn(
                  'Failed to load app from service worker. Falling back to plain <script> tag.',
                );
                loadMainDartJs();
              }
            }, 4000);
          });
        } else {
          // Service workers not supported. Just drop the <script> tag.
          loadMainDartJs();
        }
      </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Here is my pubspec.yml version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.3.0 <3.0.0"

  `cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  firebase_core: ^1.3.0
  cloud_firestore: ^2.2.2
  ars_dialog: ^1.0.8
  alert_dialog: ^1.0.0
  firebase_auth: ^1.4.1
  flutter_admin_scaffold: ^0.0.5
  firebase: ^9.0.1
  firebase_storage: ^8.1.3
  chips_choice: ^2.0.1
  flutter_switch: ^0.2.1
  email_validator: ^1.0.6`

Comment: [Code samples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) should be *minimal*, complete and representative. Information relevant to the question should be edited into the question, rather than left in comments.

Answer (score 0):

Sol.1

**On firebase init.**
What do you want to use as your public directory?

use build/web instead of public for the public directory.

If it still not working...
Sol.2
Replace the base href link ($FLUTTER_BASE_HREF) in index.html with repository's location.
`<base href="$FLUTTER_BASE_HREF">` to `<base href="/">` or `<base href="/your-repository/">`

**Right click and view page source to get the idea.**